# Datadog - Find API calls

Tags: java, endpoint, datadog, datadog-dashboard

How to find on Datadog all applications that call a specific endpoint, like "/my-endpoint/test" ?
I've tried to search on Logs, but I'm not sure if it's reliable.
What's the better way?